# jni: java.lang.AbstractMethodError when using defineClass;

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to load a class in c++ using jni (java native interface).
Everything work fine, but when using env->DefineClass it is throwing an AbstractMethodError. Any idea how to fix?

My Code:

```
jbyteArray arr = (jbyteArray) env->GetObjectArrayElement(fullArr, i);

jsize dataSize = env->GetArrayLength(arr);
jbyte* data = env->GetByteArrayElements(arr, NULL);

env->DefineClass("Test", classLoader, data, dataSize); // classLoader is the given jobject from the native method.

env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(arr, data, JNI_ABORT);
env->DeleteLocalRef(arr);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
```

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: Tell us more about class "Test", please.

Comment: Possibly the c++ class is abstract. In c++ you cannot have an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: @NickPavini What C++ class? Java doesn't care about C++ classes.

Comment: @OP Why? You could have done all this in Java.

Comment: Oh ok my mistake, so it is a java class being used in c++?

Comment: Can you load the class when you put it as a file on the classpath and use `FindClass` to load it from there? My interpretation of the error message is that the runtime thinks that the `loadClass` method in your class loader is abstract. But that would mean that your class loader object itself is somehow broken.

Comment: @MordechayS Simple main class with a main method and a normal method. That's it

Comment: @EJP For Security. C++ code can't be decompiled that easy.